# Laravel/Eloquent pagination and groupBy for a postgres materialized view model

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.8, materialized-views

I've created a materialized view: `accounts_index` that has a couple left joins, so I need to do a group by with the eloquent model. I also need to paginate the collection and am having trouble nailing the order of things. The materialized view:

```
CREATE materialized VIEW accounts_index
        AS SELECT a.account_uuid,
                  a.account_no,
                  a.person_owner_uuid,
                  a.company_owner_uuid,
                  a.account_group_uuid,
                  a.account_scope_uuid,
                  a.created_at,
                  a.deleted_at,
                  s.service_uuid,
                  s.status,
                  st.service_type
        FROM   accounts a
                LEFT JOIN services s
                        ON a.account_uuid = s.account_uuid
                LEFT JOIN service_types st
                        ON s.service_type_uuid = st.service_type_uuid
```

The eloquent model can grab that table like so: `AccountIndex::all();`.
I could paginate that: `AccountIndex::paginate();` or do a groupBy: `AccountIndex::all()->groupBy('account_uuid');`, but lost on how to combine the two. Some attempts:

- `AccountIndex::all()->groupBy('account_uuid')->paginate()`: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.`
- `AccountIndex::paginate()->groupBy('account_uuid');`: returns the collection without paginating.
- `$accountsIndex = collect(\DB::table('accounts_index')->get());
  $accountsIndex->groupBy('account_uuid')->paginate();`: Same `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.` exception.

The main problem I'm trying to solve is that these joins will be returning accounts that have multiple services (so multiple rows) and I need to then group by the `account_uuid`. Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

`paginate` method is related to `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` or `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` classes, it is not exists in `Collection` class,
the corresponding method for it in `Collection` class is `forPage` method, you can get more information from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forpage)

Comment: That loses all pagination meta-data. I want to group by first and then paginate with full meta-data.

Comment: so you should to apply groupBy on database level but then you will have only one row for each account

Comment: That would lose the multiple services that each account could have.

Answer (score 0):

almost

`AccountIndex::groupBy('account_uuid')->paginate()`

paginate actually DOES something

`groupBy()` is just writing SQL just like `->where()` `->join()` etc that all prepares an SQL statement you can try by running `->toSql()` returns an sql string.

`get()` `all()` `paginate()` all actually do something e.g. execute the SQL.